# Why quarks are confined? Why can't they be found in unbound states?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, confinement

No one has observed before a "free" quark, i.e. a quark in an unbound state. According to one paper, I read that $p\bar{p}$ collision produce unbound $t\bar{t}$ pair which quickly decay into other particles. But some people argue that the produced $t\bar{t}$ pairs decay so quickly that they had no time to bind! And I agree with this idea.

So why can one not find quarks in unbound states?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_confinement

Comment: Not a duplicate but closely related (for gluons instead of quarks): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/563495/226902

Comment: More about quark confinement: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/530710/226902 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/227770/226902 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/274495/226902 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131416/226902 . A nice toy-model picture: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/538862/226902 . What is confinement in simple terms: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/529796/226902 . Closely related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45514/226902 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141926/226902 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the force-versus-distance law for quarks is such that the farther away from one another you pull a pair of quarks, the harder they attract one another. It is as if they were attached to each other with a rubber band (a very stiff one!). If you pull them far enough apart, there's enough energy stored in the system to create a new pair of quarks (i.e., the rubber band snaps) which pair up with the others and instead of getting two "free" quarks, you get a pair of mesons with two quarks inside each one.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more descriptive and a simple mathematical treatment using the formulation of electrodynamics and quantum mechanics, then Leonard Susskind's series of lectures will give you a lot of insights!!

Here is the Link : https://inspirehep.net/literature/1532

Answer (score 1):

Quarks that are lighter than the QCD scale, ($\sim 200\,{\rm MeV}$) will always be confined, but heavier ones can be unbound. The top quark weighs $170\,{\rm GeV}$, so it can be unbound.

The QCD scale is the mass scale that pops out when you renormalize the strong interactions.